Java 8 Streams API grouping by two fields and return updated Collection
I have java custom class i.e Employee having below fields,
public class Employee {
     private String name;
     private String dept;
     private Integer age;
     private Double salary;
}

public Employee(String name, String dept, Integer age, Double salary) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dept = dept;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.age = age;
}
//getter and setters

My list object has below data,
List<Employee> list = Arrays.asList(
            new Employee("mahesh", "IT", 25, 1000.00), 
            new Employee("rajesh", "IT", 30, 1200.00), 
            new Employee("Saket", "IT", 30, 1000.00), 
            new Employee("Samuel", "IT", 30, 1150.00), 
            new Employee("Anil", "Eng", 29, 2000.00),
            new Employee("Sachin", "Eng", 29, 2000.00));

I have to iterate this list and updated list should return first, third, fifth and sixth records.
group the records using department and salary and if the grouping count greater than 1 those records should return.
In the above example, second and fourth it's occured one time as grouping so those records should skip.
So final List should contain these records,
 List<Employee> list = Arrays.asList(
            new Employee("mahesh", "IT", 25, 1000.00), 
            new Employee("Saket", "IT", 30, 1000.00), 
            new Employee("Anil", "Eng", 29, 2000.00),
            new Employee("Sachin", "Eng", 29, 2000.00));

Need to group based on two fields i.e department and salary and the stream api should return updated list.

“updated list should return first, third, fifth and sixth records” — Why? You’ve got some explaining to do. Show expected output, and explain why. Voting to close as unclear. And likely a duplicate too.

@BasilBourque because first and third have same department, i.e. "IT" and same salary, i.e. 1000.00. Likewise fifth and sixth, i.e. department is "Eng" and salary is 2000.00 for both. What is not clear?

@Abra A good Question states its requirements explicitly rather than makes me guess.

@BasilBourque I didn't have to guess.

If you are interested in elements that are not unique when grouped by a combination of department and salary, you can perform a grouping and filter based on the count. This would further need flat mapping the elements back for the data structure desired in the output:
    List<Employee> employees = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(employee -> employee.dept + employee.salary))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
            .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

Note: This relies on the uniqueness of the key created with the combination of department and salary represented as of type String.

it worked as expected.

Why do people always come up with the unreliable and inefficient string concatenation for creating a compound key? Just using the grouping function employee -> Arrays.asList(employee.dept, employee.salary) provides a reliable group key. By the way, you can stream over values() instead of entrySet() in the first place, then you don’t need to call getValue()…

you  can try following code snippet

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> list = Arrays.asList(
            new Employee("mahesh", "IT", 25, 1000.00), 
            new Employee("rajesh", "IT", 30, 1200.00), 
            new Employee("Saket", "IT", 30, 1000.00), 
            new Employee("Samuel", "IT", 30, 1150.00), 
            new Employee("Anil", "Eng", 29, 2000.00),
            new Employee("Sachin", "Eng", 29, 2000.00)
        );

        
        // Group by concatenated department and salary key
        Map<String, List<Employee>> groupedByDeptAndSalary = filteredList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(emp -> emp.getDept() + "-" + emp.getSalary()));

        // Flatten the groups and retain only those with more than one element
        List<Employee> result = groupedByDeptAndSalary.values().stream()
            .filter(group -> group.size() > 1)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        result.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

In this solution:
1.group the filtered employees by department and salary (compose them as identifier).
2.flatten the groups and filter to retain only those groups with more than one employee.
3.collect the results and print them.
This should give you the desired output:
Employee{name='mahesh', dept='IT', age=25, salary=1000.0}
Employee{name='Saket', dept='IT', age=30, salary=1000.0}
Employee{name='Anil', dept='Eng', age=29, salary=2000.0}
Employee{name='Sachin', dept='Eng', age=29, salary=2000.0}


My understanding was that criterion 1 was a description of the desired output, not a step in the grouping/filtering process.

@AndrewYim you are correct.

oh i got the point, i ''ll modify answer
